# How to be able to draw a graph like this?

Tags: flutter, dart

[My Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVtcj.png)

I'm having some trouble drawing this chart, hope someone can help me.

Comment: You can draw it using this library https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart

Remark: you should provide what work you have done, or share some code in SO questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this package [syncfusion](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts).This package have a documentation which you can easily create charts.I tried and it is really usable .

https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts